# PHP - IF statement always True In While loop

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach, while-loop

Im Currently developing in the adwords SDK.
Im querying whether the products are in stock from the database and setting the ad to either paused or enabled.

Now in my while loop i have an IF statement that is currently always firing true for some reason. I think maybe its only using the first value and not looping through $stock, if thats the case any ideas?

I need it to run through each stock status. IF 'In Stock' post enabled else set it to paused

Heres the code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM MYDB.MYTBL" ;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result) {

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $adGroup = $row['adgroup'];
    $adGroupId = $row['adgroup_id'];
    $product = $row['product'];
    $stock = $row['stock'];
    $client = $row['client'];


    if ($stock === "In Stock") {

      if(!function_exists('UpdateAdGroupExample')){

        function UpdateAdGroupExample(AdWordsUser $user, $adGroupId) {
          // Get the service, which loads the required classes.
          $adGroupService = $user->GetService('AdGroupService', ADWORDS_VERSION);

          // Create ad group using an existing ID.
          $adGroup = new AdGroup();
          $adGroup->id = $adGroupId;

          // Update the status.
          $adGroup->status = 'ENABLED';

          // Create operation.
          $operation = new AdGroupOperation();
          $operation->operand = $adGroup;
          $operation->operator = 'SET';

          $operations = array($operation);

          // Make the mutate request.
          $result = $adGroupService->mutate($operations);

          // Display result.
          $adGroup = $result->value[0];
          printf("Ad group with ID '%s' has updated default bid '$%s'.\n", $adGroup->id,
              $adGroup->status);

        }

        try {
          // Get AdWordsUser from credentials in "../auth.ini"
          // relative to the AdWordsUser.php file's directory.
          $user = new AdWordsUser();
          $user->SetClientCustomerId('XXXXXXXXX');
          // Log every SOAP XML request and response.
          $user->LogAll();

          // Run the example.
          UpdateAdGroupExample($user, $adGroupId);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          printf("An error has occurred: %s\n", $e->getMessage());
        }
      }
      try {
        // Get AdWordsUser from credentials in "../auth.ini"
        // relative to the AdWordsUser.php file's directory.
        $user = new AdWordsUser();
        $user->SetClientCustomerId('XXXXXXXXX');
        // Log every SOAP XML request and response.
        $user->LogAll();

        // Run the example.
        UpdateAdGroupExample($user, $adGroupId);
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        printf("An error has occurred: %s\n", $e->getMessage());
      }
```

Comment: u have 2 ifs :D if its the `if ($stock === "In Stock")` remove 1 ` = ` from it

Comment: @KikiTheOne lol ;)

Comment: In your inner function you override variable $result - maybe this is a problem. If not, it means that all your records are "In Stock" :)

Comment: let me ask 1 question. why u declare the function in a WhileLoop ? instead of outside the Loop and just CALL it once ?

Comment: @nospor i think this will be the error, since he loops while $result fetch_array. So, if result is not the samy anymore, there is nothing to be looped trough.
To check if it stucks after first loop, place an echo $row['stock'] in the while loop. If there's only one value, you know the loop is broken.

Comment: i have to go with assumption everything is "In Stock". You don't really need to use === though.

Comment: @nospor Yes $stock only shows once but it seems to loop through all the rest and posts the all as Enabled

Comment: Ive changed the $result variable but still dont work. i have also checked and the products are not all in stock

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the function would be declared within a loop like it was - more commonly you would declare it before any such loop. It's likely I may have missed the point but I'd have thought you could do something along these lines.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM MYDB.MYTBL" ;
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );

if( $result ) {

    if( !function_exists( 'UpdateAdGroupExample' ) ){

        function UpdateAdGroupExample( AdWordsUser $user, $adGroupId ) {
          // Get the service, which loads the required classes.
          $adGroupService = $user->GetService( 'AdGroupService', ADWORDS_VERSION );

          // Create ad group using an existing ID.
          $adGroup = new AdGroup();
          $adGroup->id = $adGroupId;

          // Update the status.
          $adGroup->status = 'ENABLED';

          // Create operation.
          $operation = new AdGroupOperation();
          $operation->operand = $adGroup;
          $operation->operator = 'SET';

          $operations = array( $operation );

          // Make the mutate request.
          $result = $adGroupService->mutate( $operations );

          // Display result.
          $adGroup = $result->value[0];

          printf( "Ad-Group with ID '%s' has updated default bid '$%s'.\n", $adGroup->id, $adGroup->status );
        }
    }



    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
        /* appear unused ~ is there further code in the loop not shown? */
        #$adGroup = $row['adgroup'];
        #$product = $row['product'];
        #$client = $row['client'];

        $adGroupId = $row['adgroup_id'];
        $stock = trim( $row['stock'] );


        if ( $stock == "In Stock" ) {

            try {
                $user = new AdWordsUser();
                if( $user ){

                    $user->SetClientCustomerId('XXXXXXXXX');
                    $user->LogAll();

                    UpdateAdGroupExample( $user, $adGroupId );
                } else {
                    throw new Exception('User could not be created');
                }
            } catch( Exception $e ) {
                printf( "An exception has occurred: %s\n", $e->getMessage() );
            }
        } else {
            /* debug what the value of $stock is */
            printf("stock: %s\n",$stock);

        }/* end stock check */

    }/* end while */

}/* end if( $result ) */
```

Comment: Still not sure if this line $result = $adGroupService->mutate( $operations ); will not cause any problem, since you're overwriting result... May you know more than me x:

Comment: @RamRaider - I think your Answer will definitely work i just need to be able to use this line $adGroup->status = 'ENABLED'; in the if ( $stock == "In Stock" ) statement.